# How can I run GUI applications in an X-forwarded GNOME Terminal instance?

Tags: ssh, xforwarding

I usually work in an X-forwarded GNOME Terminal session, which I launch like this:

```
local-machine$ ssh -X remote-machine gnome-terminal
```

I do this instead of running SSH in my local terminal because it means that new tabs will open on the remote host in the same directory ([related unresolved question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729995/how-can-i-configure-gnome-terminal-to-launch-new-tabs-with-the-same-ssh-host-and)).

I've noticed that when I try to launch a GUI program from this X-forwarded terminal, it fails, e.g.

```
remote-machine$ gedit

(gedit:49577): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:32:45.928: cannot open display: localhost:13.0
```

However, if I also run a separate X-forwarded shell session (and just leave it sitting there):

```
local-machine$ ssh -X remote-machine
```

then I can run GUI apps like `gedit` in the X-forwarded GNOME Terminal instance.

Why does this work-around work? Is there a simpler way to do this (e.g. a flag that I can add to the `ssh -X remote-machine gnome-terminal` command)?